# Higher power than 2 for white noise time series?

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, white-noise

Let $\{Yt\}$ given by $Y_{t} = Z_{t}$

With $Z_{t} \sim{N}(0,\sigma^{2})$

What are $E[Y_t^{3}]$ and $ E[Y_t^{4}]$?

Answer (score 2):

Since $Y_t=Z_t$ are normal random variables, you can use the moments defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#/Moments). That is

$$E[Y_t^3]=0, \ \ \ \ \ \ E[Y_t^4]=3\sigma^4$$